# What does "holding the cup at the other end of the string" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm trying to comprehend the actual meaning of this line in context — "She was my only connection, holding the cup at the other end of the string" — from a memoir book I'm reading. I assumed that *holding the cup at the other end of the string* could possibly be an idiom phrase but I couldn't find so either in my different keyword search in Google. Hope someone can help to clarify the meaning in this context.

Here is the context of the line from the book, *I Came Upon a Lighthouse* By Shantanu Naidu:

> *Vivaan would go out on hikes and meets to introduce himself to our new classmates as they arrived in Ithaca. It felt like I was already
> missing out and school hadn't even started. More and more time was
> spent with Tuhina on the phone as I recovered as slowly as possible.
> She was my only connection, holding the cup at the other end of the
> string.*

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's not an (established) idiomatic phrase, but a metaphorical one.

> [...] holding the cup at the other end of the string.

Literally, it refers to two people talking to each other using only two cups<sup>1</sup> and a string. [More here](https://science.howstuffworks.com/question410.htm).

> [image: picture]
>
> ([Source](http://pukekoroomkokatahi.blogspot.com/2012/02/munching-mikes-mobile.html))

---

> She was my only connection [...]

Here, the word "connection" could very well mean a "[link between two phones](https://www.lexico.com/definition/connection)", the same way that a piece of string forms a link between two cups. Therefore, figuratively, I believe **one** string connotes "a single, or the *only*, connection between two people (i.e., the author and Tuhina)".

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Specifically, paper cups or plastic cups. Tin cans or similarly shaped items can also be used.</sup>

Comment: This is indeed the only and correct answer. A very taut string carries sound from the cup or tin (acting as a microphone) at one end to the cup or container (acting as loudspeaker) at the other.

Comment: The bottom of the vessel acts as a diaphragm.  So a china cup won't work.  The classic self-made toy is two used tin cans with holes pierced in their bottoms and taught string or wire between.  A talks into one while B puts the other can to their ear.  (I wonder if there is some translation going on also.)

Comment: @PeterFox A disposable plastic cup would work, but perhaps not as well as a tin can. The big problem is that any contact with the string kills the vibrations so you can only communicate over short distances in straight lines. I think the quoted reference is metaphorical rather than literal.

Comment: For the benefit of the future visitors to this page, it should be emphasised that this is not an established idiom of any kind. It is a one-off metaphor that may, perhaps, be effective if the readers played with such 'phones' as children, but is likely to be utterly confusing to those who never have (i.e. to almost everybody in the younger generations).

Comment: If it’s an older book, the telephone she was using would have been a landline with a wire to a box on the wall, and a cord to the receiver. So it would also be a metaphor for talking over a copper wire, with a pair of landline phones.

Comment: @Davislor But the receiver of a landline phone would not be referred to as a cup, and a landline phone would enable the possibility to talk to numerous other people; whereas the metaphor of two cups connected by a sting could only be used by two people, thus leading to "She was my only connection".

Comment: Some further meaning I get from this passage: the cups-and-string toy only works if both participants make it work. Both have to actively hold the string taut and one person has to make an effort to listen when the other is talking. The author here is saying not only is Tuhina the only person she talks to, but she is dependent on Tuhina wanting to be there to listen. It is a very descriptive metaphor for how tenuous the connection is.

Comment: @GlenYates I think the metaphor is a bit less literal than that. Also, telephone receivers a century ago were shaped like cups.

Comment: I added a picture, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @GEdgar: I don't mind at all, thank you :)

Comment: A cup and string never seems to work very well, at least based on my childhood experience, but it's a [very famous traditional toy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_can_telephone), such that people (at least of a certain age) would probably be familiar. Maybe kids todays have alternative toys.

Comment: It is somewhat puzzling why both the original text and all contributions to this page keep using the word *cup* in describing this toy; *can* or *tin* would have made it much clearer what it is.

Comment: @jsw29 I think it depends when you were born - Look at the picture - they use plastic cups - yes older people would use tin cans

Comment: @jsw29 I have no recollection of playing with such a device but it's what I immediately thought of on reading the question.  Being aware of their existence is enough.

Comment: I think using this phrase emphasises the poor quality of the actual connection, likening it to the low-tech two cans and a piece of string. I use this myself when making a derogatory description of a badly implemented/designed (usually computer-computer) connection.

Comment: @jsw29 Are you suggesting that younger generations no longer play games?

Comment: I remember making and using these using tin cans and string. Memory says that the quality was surprisingly good. That was 60+ years ago so memory of quality may be fading :-) .

Comment: @mmmmmm, yes, the toy can be made of plastic cups, but the **word** *cup* does not immediately make one think of **plastic** cups. It is more likely to first bring to mind something like a teacup made of china, which, as has been pointed out above, definitely wouldn't work.